# Is there a feature on Stack Overflow that detects the same person having multiple accounts?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Does Stack Overflow have a feature in place that monitors two people having the same account on the basis of name and more interestingly questions of one answered by another and vice versa? It would be really cool to have such a monitoring process.

For example, I see this behavior in the following accounts.

- users/4702905/john-mackinnon
- users/4760085/john-mackinnon

Even if the user has created two accounts, let's say by mistake, there should be a way to merge these accounts. Another feature that could be added?

Lastly, do we today have any manual process to merge or report such issues?

Comment: Can't you change your displayed username at will?  And why can't there be legitimately be two "John MacKinnon"?  There are [> 34k people named John Smith in the U.S.](http://names.whitepages.com/John/Smith) and 186 named John MacKinnon.

Comment: Sure there can be. If you ask me particular about these accounts then I saw each account providing answer to other and getting upvotes and accepted. I am not asserting that they may be so called "sock-puppets" as the below answer suggest. I am merely curious if there is any checking and reporting mechanism is place.

Comment: @AniketThakur It's not clear to me what point your question is about if it isn't either about duplicate usernames or about sockpuppets.

Comment: I'm absolutely *shocked* that you don't have multiple accounts. Normally when people come around asking about whether or not we have methods to detect sock puppets, we find that they have a whole drawer full of them. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're generally referred to as "Sock Puppet" accounts, and yes, such a monitoring process exists, though its details aren't generally published.